# Setting character encoding doesn't take effect

Tags: java, utf-8

In `JSP` , I post `utf-8` form to server, I capture the post message：

[image]

[image]

The text `"中文"` `utf-8` code is `E4B8AD` `E69687`

## so I am sure the `JSP` code is `utf-8`

In Java I set a filter in `web.xml`

```
<filter>
    <description>desc-CharacterEncodingFilter</description>
    <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.linkage.rainbow.ui.filter.SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
     <init-param>
         <param-name>encoding</param-name>
         <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
     </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern></filter-mapping>
```

filter code i hava set

```
{
    if(this.ignore || request.getCharacterEncoding() == null) {
        String encoding = this.selectEncoding(request);
        if(encoding != null) {
            request.setCharacterEncoding(encoding);
            response.setCharacterEncoding(encoding);
        }
    }

    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

debug info encoding is utf-8 I set Tomcat config file conf/server.xml

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

IDEA tomcat setting VM options:

```
 -server -XX:PermSize=128M -XX:MaxPermSize=512M
```

My development tool is IDEA, platform is Windows, bug it don't effect. Can anyone help me !!

I modify my code ：

```
String test = new String(contract.getDescriptor().getBytes("iso-8859-1"),"UTF-8");
```

it work !!
my form data is :

```
contract.name:pro-i_srv_synch_chain_chl
contract.contractId:100000372
contract.code:pro-i_srv_synch_chain_chl
contract.isBase:0
contract.baseContractId:
contract.descriptor:中文
```

dost `HttpServletRequest#setCharacterEncoding()` not effect Child node?
I still don't understand the reason

Comment: the controller request.getParameter("contract.descriptor")  hex code is E4B8AD E69687, but to my action  class Member String descriptor show hex code，don't show chinese text

Comment: How do you test it does not work? Please [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Then Add the code to your question.

Comment: How do you use Struts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the Reason is my filter

```
<filter>
    <description>desc-CharacterEncodingFilter</description>
    <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.linkage.rainbow.ui.filter.SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
     <init-param>
         <param-name>encoding</param-name>
         <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
     </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern></filter-mapping>
```

is after my XSSFilter.

so I adjust the CharacterEncodingFilter to the first filter, it work ok!